# Images not showing when foreach loop working in _PartialView Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a model class like following

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public UserViewModel() 
    {
        UsersDet = new Dictionary<long, string>(); 
        usrdat  = new List<User>();    
    }

    public Dictionary<long , string> UsersDet { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<User> usrdata { get; set; }
}
```

Then I'm trying to get those model values in partial view like following

this partial view is a popup actually.

**_UserView partial view**

```
@model Project.ViewModels.UserViewModel

<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body" style="width: 530px;">
            <div id="slider_view" style="display: block;">
                <div class="flexslider">
                    <ul class="slides">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.UsersDet )
                        {         
                            <li data-thumb="~/Upload_Images/A.jpg">
                                <img src="~/Upload_Images/A.jpg" data-imagedata="image001" />
                                <p class="flex-caption">Title</p>
                            </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I cannot see the `A.jpg` images in Popup, but when I use like following I can see images

**_UserView partial view**

```
@model Project.ViewModels.UserViewModel

<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body" style="width: 530px;">
            <div id="slider_view" style="display: block;">
                <div class="flexslider">
                    <ul class="slides">
                        @for (int i =0; i < 3 ; i ++)
                        {         
                            <li data-thumb="~/Upload_Images/A.jpg">
                                <img src="~/Upload_Images/A.jpg" data-imagedata="image001" />
                                <p class="flex-caption">Title</p>
                            </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is controller method to bind values to above popup

```
    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult MethodName(int id)
    {
        try
        {    

            IEnumerable<User> listofData = ..
            UserViewModel listofimage = new UserViewModel();


            if (listofData != null) 
            {
                listofimage.usrdata = listofData;

                foreach(var item in listofimage.usrdata)
                {
                    var path = RenderImage(item.ImageValue, "UploadImagePath");                        

                    var fileResult = path as FilePathResult;

                    if (fileResult != null)
                    {

                        string imageurl = fileResult.FileName;

                        imageurl = imageurl.Replace(@"\\", @"\");

                        listofimage.UsersDet.Add(item.CaseID, imageurl);
                    }                        
                }
            }                

            return PartialView("_UserView", listofimages);   

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

    } 

    public ActionResult RenderImage(string imageid, string pathvalue)
    {
        try
        {
            var URL = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[pathvalue].ToString();
            var path = Path.Combine(URL, imageid + ".jpg");
            return base.File(path, "image/jpeg");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Whats is wrong in my `foreach` approach how to populate elements as loop

Comment: Are there any items in `UsersDet ` (where do you populate it)?

Comment: yeah multiple items may include

Comment: @kez `Model.UsersDet` doesn't contains any item, debug your code or at least show number of items before foreach loop `<span>@Model.UsersDet.Count</span>`

Comment: @AhmedRagheb  question updated , values getting actually when I debug I can see that,

Comment: The only way that `@foreach (var item in Model.UsersDet )` could not be generating any html is if there are no items in the collection (and still using the nonsense from the last question I see :)

Comment: @kez Convert `IEnumerable<User> listofData` = .. to `List<User>` `.toList()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke do need to use  to get images, for ex: `<li data-thumb=@Url.Content("~/Upload_Images/A.jpg")>`

Comment: Sorry, what does that have to do with the question?

Comment: to show images with foreach loop do I have to use like this `<li data-thumb=@Url.Content("~/Upload_Images/A.jpg")>` other than this `<li data-thumb="~/Upload_Images/A.jpg">`

Comment: @StephenMuecke is that the reason image not showing when use `foreach` as you mention in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40670382/get-viewpage-values-from-layout-page) as  comment `(1). You cannot use foreach loops to generate form controls for a collection - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) (2). Duplicate id attributes are invalid - use class names and relative selectors`

Comment: No. And what is your real problem - the code inside the `foreach` and `for` loops are identical - if your claiming the the `for` loops generated your html but the `foreach` loop does not then the is only one reason - you DO NOT have any items in the collection (or you have not shown the correct code and they are actually different in each loop)

Answer (score 0):

If Model.UsersDet is populated with items then < li > elements will be rendered. If they are rendered but you don't see the images then you open the devtools and in the Network tab you look for the requests made for each image. If there requests have bad response then you fixed it according to the returned http status.

But not having the project to debug and if you are saying that @for is working but @foreach is not then the problem should be that the Model.UsersDet is empty.

Comment: :) that's a good possibility , but I'm debugging from partialview , I can see Model.UsersDet count also

Comment: @kez as everything in web it is all about the requests and their responses then :)